# Separate SPA frontend app into different repositories

Tags: module, package, single-page-application

Does somebody have experience in separating single page front-end application into separate packages, I mean not just back-end / front-end, but client application (in my case angular 2) and not angular modules but separate npm packages (like each package contains separate application). Notice here we still planing to use shared modules (again via packages).
So maybe somebody have real life experience with this approach, what is the pros / cons ?

So pros here:

1. Separate code base, different teams work with separate repositories.
2. Can update versions of 3d party libraries (angular for example) separately for each package-application without affecting others.

Help will be really appreciated, can't find on the web anything about this.

Comment: Shame that such a great questions are left unanswered :(